# How to make a prepared statement with multiple parameters on a PostgreSQL DB in PHP

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement

```
    if (isset ($_POST['valider'])) {
        if (isset ($_POST['nom']) && isset ($_POST['num']) && isset($_POST['suffixe']) && isset($_POST['rue']) && isset($_POST['cp']) && isset($_POST['ville'])){
            $nom = $_POST['nom'];
            $num = $_POST['num'];
            $suffixe = $_POST['suffixe'];
            $rue = $_POST['rue'];
            $cp = $_POST['cp'];
            $ville = $_POST['ville'];

            pg_prepare($dbconn, "query1", 'SELECT id FROM public."City" WHERE zip_code = $1 AND name = $2') or die ("Cannot prepare statement\n");
            $result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query1", array($cp, $ville)) or die ("Cannot execute statement\n");
            pg_close($dbconn);
}
```

We expected '3' but we found 'Resource ID #7' in $result.

We are participating to a hackathon and any help would be really appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: is PDO not an option?

Comment: We are prohibited from using frameworks (The aim of this hackaton is to make an ultra-light dynamic website).

Comment: Found __where__? I don't see any output here.

Comment: Also what do you expect from INSERT with WHERE clause?

Comment: PDO is not a framework, it's a generic way to connect to any DB

Comment: It is a SELECT, not an INSERT (my bad, I've been coding for 14 hours straight), but replacing that did not fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch the results in to an array:

```
pg_prepare($dbconn, "query1", 'SELECT id FROM public."City" WHERE zip_code = $1 AND name = $2') or die ("Cannot prepare statement\n");
$result = pg_execute($dbconn, "query1", array($cp, $ville)) or die ("Cannot execute statement\n");
$f = pg_fetch_all($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($f); $i++) {
  // Do something:
  // print ($f[$i]['id']);
}
```

You can also use `pg_fetch_row()` to iterate.

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)